# Azure trigger linked template defaultValue

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm using Linked Templates in Azure ARM templates. I have a problem trying to use the default value of a sub template but still maintaining in the parent template the reference to a parameter.

**parent.json**

```
...
parameters: {
  foo: {
    type: "string"
  }
},
resources: [{
  type: "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  properties: {
    templateLink: {
      uri: "sub.json",
      contentVersion: "1.0.0.0"
    },
    parameters: {
      bar: {
        value: "[parameters('foo')]"
      }
    }
  }
}]
...
```

**sub.json**

```
...
parameters: {
  bar: {
    type: "string",
    allowedValues: ["larry", "moe", "curly"],
    defaultValue: "curly"
  }
}
...
```

Unfortunately, passing the **null** value for foo in the parent template will error `The value of deployment parameter 'foo' is null`.  If I pass an empty string for foo, it will error `The provided value '' for the template parameter 'bar' is not valid. The parameter value is not part of the allowed value(s): 'larry,moe,curly'`.

I tried putting in parent.json

```
...
resources: [{
  type: "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
  properties: {
  ...
    parameters: {
      bar: {
        value: "[if(empty(parameters('foo')), json('null'), parameters('foo'))]"
      }
    }
  }
}]
...
```

but it'll just give the same value is null.  I know this can be done in AWS nested stacks using value `aws::NoValue` but couldn't find any equivalent in azure. Would anyone know anything else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dont pass anything, dont even specify the parameter name. so pass in:

```
parameters: {}
```

I did never try it, but you might be able to achieve the desired outcome with something like:

```
parameters: "[variables('passMe')]"
```

and for the variables value you can use something like:

```
passMe: {
    bar: {
         value: "bla-bla-bla"
    }
}
```

You will obviously need to construct these variables on the fly or at least partially on the fly.

Comment: yeah technically that's what i'm finding, the only problem with this is that you're forcing the user to use the defaultValue and if they want to change it they have to edit the template instead of just passing in a value for the parameter.

Comment: well, you can `synch` the default value in both templates, so if nothing gets passed you will pass in the same default value to the template. also, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Found the negative to this is that you cannot use runtime states in variables so if you need to pass a property using another resource's runtime state you have to directly declare it in the parameters and not through a variable

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else in the future... expanding on @4c74356b41's response. Create variables that can dynamically generate the linked template's parameters at runtime.

Here's a working sample:

```json
...
parameters: {
  foo: {
    type: "string"
  }
},
variables: {
  emptyObject: {},
  subParameterBar: {
    bar: {
      value: "[parameters('foo')]"
    }
  },
  hasSubParameterBar: "[if(empty(parameters('foo')), variables('emptyObject'), variables('subParameterBar'))]",
  subProperties: "unionvariables('HasSubParameterBar'), ...<any other parameter variables>)]"
},
resources: [{
  type: "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  name: "sub",
  properties: {
    templateLink: {
      uri: "sub.json",
      contentVersion: "1.0.0.0"
    },
    parameters: "[variables('barProperties')]"
  }
}]
...
```